# Is there a ConTeXt command to print the path of the file in which it is evoked?

Tags: context, context-mkiv, filesystem-access, file-lookup

I would like to put a URL-link in the output PDF of a ConTeXt file. It should point to the directory in which the ConTeXt file and its output PDF reside.

Currently, I am using a shell script in my [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html)-workflow to achieve this. I am just wondering if there were a more straightforward way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lfs.currentdir()` function to find the name of the directory from which `context` was invoked.

```
\ctxlua{context(lfs.currentdir())}
```

Use `environment.inputfilename` to get the name of the input filename

```
\ctxlua{context(environment.inputfilename)}
```

Combine the two to get the full path to the directory where the file is (this does not normalize relative paths, so might end up with `/tmp/abc/./test`.

```
local fullname = file.join(lfs.currentdir(), environment.inputfilename)
print(fullname)
local pwd = file.dirname(fullname)
print(pwd)
```